# Problem in evaluation of a solution and plotting

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I've written out a code which solves a equation and uses this solution to find "ph".

```
L = 1.0; h0 = 0; h1 = 1.0;
dh = 0.01; iter = IntegerPart[(h1 - h0)/dh];
dphi = {{0, 0}};
Do[{sols = 
    NDSolve[{f''[x] == (h0 + n dh)^2/f[x]^3 - f[x] (1 - f[x]^2), 
      f[0] == f[L] == 1}, f[x], x, 
     Method -> {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0}, 
       MaxIterations -> 100}];
   ph = NIntegrate[(h0 + n dh)/(f[x] /. sols)^2, {x, 0, L}]; 
   AppendTo[dphi, {ph[[1]], h0 + n dh}]},
  {n, iter}];
p1 = ListPlot[dphi]
```

[image: The plot]

Now the actual plot should look like this.
[image: Actual plot]
In my code I've taken L//[] Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Because you are calculating only part of one curve, you should not expect to have all of all four curves.  What does `L//[]` mean?

Comment: You generate `dphi` with a single x value for each of the monotonically increasing y values. So you cannot possibly expect to get a plot like the image you posted.

Comment: @bbgodfrey sorry there was a writing mistake. It will be L/(/[xi]) as shown in the attached fig. and I've in my code I've taken it to be just x. And yes my code is only for the first curve with L/(/[xi])=1. For other cases I've different intial conditions

Answer (score 1):

Its not really clear what you are asking, but here is a cleaned up version of your code:

```
  L = 1;
  dphi[v_] := (
      s = f[x] /. First@NDSolve[
            {f''[x] == v^2/f[x]^3 - f[x] (1 - f[x]^2), f[0] == f[L] == 1},
            f[x], x,
            Method -> {"Shooting", 
                       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0},
                       MaxIterations -> 100}];
       v NIntegrate[1/s^2, {x, 0, L}])
  ParametricPlot[ {dphi[v], v} , {v, 0, 1.06517}]
```

[image]

note the max is ~1.06 while you stopped at 1 ( is that the question? )

There is no xi in your formulation so I don't know about the rest of the plot.

-Edit-

the other half of the plot seems to be associated with a different initial condition, try:

```
 "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 1, f'[0] == -2}
```